# add dynamic loaded images to appcache at run time

Tags: html, angularjs, offline, html5-appcache

I am creating a offline supported application. For that all js/css/html are added to cache-manifest and working fine, but now in content there are images whose path I don't know until its  there in content. Can we update appcahce at runtime?
The same question is for css, there is a custom css that is included in application but again path is not certain.
Is there a way that we can include css/images to appcache at runtime ?
Thanks!!!

Comment: did u find any solution?

Comment: I solved the issue by generating appcache at runtime.